# javascript: Creating a script element for an urbanspoon widget: doesn't load

Tags: javascript

**Background**

The urbanspoon reservation widget loads via a script tag. Within the script is one massive document.write that loads all the css and html for the widget. You place the script tags within the html you want the widget to load in(i know...)

**Problem**

Well, this widget is really slow to load and is blocking the loading of other assets. So in attempts to optimize it a little, i'm trying to inject the script tag into the element only when that particular section is requested. Only problem is that the content is not loading.

As per another SO answer, i'm creating a script tag and then populating it with the necessary parameters.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'long url';
$("#scriptWrapper").append(script);
```

Everything injects fine and is correct. Problem is that the script is not successfully injecting the content.

**Here's a link showing what is returned by the widget link**
    http://www.urbanspoon.com/b/posts/5191

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors inside the other script? Is it loaded at all?

Comment: @Sirko I checked, no errors! :(

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try [jQuery.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

Comment: Tried it. the script contents is a giant document.write() so I believe that was contributing it to not working. Does it do anything different than a script element would?

Comment: Hmm, you can try store the content to variable and strip 'document.write(' and ');' than use document.write(variable);